# jquery Accordion : drop down list is not getting hided eventhought the master containers visibilty is false

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, accordion, visibility

I have a page where i am using jquery accordion to show /toggle some content.I have placed all the accordion content inside a div called divAccordionHolder.When the page loads initially, i dont want to show this div,When user clicks a button in the page,the div which has accordion would be visible.I have set the visibility of the divAccordionHolder flase in the page and in document.ready i am applying the accordion  as

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#accordion").accordion();
```

Now my problem is , when the page loads the divAccordionHolder div is showing for few seconds and then disappear. Can any one tell me how to avoid this ?

I noted that the dropdown list controls which are present inside the divAccordionHolder  is the item swhich is visible in the time of pageload.All other controls like button,label are not coming for this blinking

Can any one guide me how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Add  style="display:none" on div or in CSS style.

Or better move div -1000 px with css, and remove position style when end init event of accordion is triggered.